# Does an Observer appear in every episode of Fringe?

Tags: fringe

I have only recently begun to watch Fringe. I just finished season one and am two episodes into season two. I have noticed an Observer in most episodes of the series. Sometimes the Observer is plainly obvious even interacting with principal characters. Other times the Observer is seen only briefly or is hidden in the background.

Is an Observer (not sure if there is only one or many at this point) in every episode? If not every episode is there a list of the episodes where the Observer does not appear? Does the Observer only show up for particular types of events?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, there is an Observer in *every* episode. [FringePedia provides an Observer Appearance guide](http://fringepedia.net/wiki/Observer_Appearance) with photos of each appearance and time stamps of where the Observer can be observed from the episode.

You can also search for the [episode reviews](http://www.sfx.co.uk/search/fringe+episode+review) on the SFX website, every review has a section called 'Observing the Observer' that tells you where to spot them.

Comment: Oh, good!  There is another Fringe Wiki.  I'd first found the one on Wikia, and thus far have been a bit disappointed with its quality.  Much thanks for the info here.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand it, while many Observers come and go through the life of the series, the one designated "September" appears in every episode of the first four seasons.

Comment: You should add evidence to back up your answer.